# C++ expandable application with dll's

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plugins, interface, abstract

I want to make an C++ application which is highly expandable. The basic idea is a main application which contains of some basic functionality and the application life cycle (when what is executed). This main application can be extended with dll's.

Let's assume there is a folder for the main application where you can put your dll's. When you start the main application it loads these and execute implemented functionality in these dll's.

What is the best approach to this (preferred without frameworks or other dependencies)?

My thoughts were to load dynamically dll's. Theses dll's implement some abstract Classes/Interfaces, so that the main application can work with these abstract Classes/Interfaces and the specific implementation is in the dll's.

Comment: Pardon the perhaps not-so-obvious question: Why are you're reinventing [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#:~:text=Component%20Object%20Model%20(COM)%20is,large%20range%20of%20programming%20languages.) on the very platform where it has already resided for 30 years?

Comment: @WhozCraig Is there a better idea for such a plugin system which i demonstrated in the question above? I want a main application which can be expanded by other developers who may or may not see the complete source code of the main application.

Comment: @Vennox Unlike the Win32 C ABI, there is no universal C++ ABI, and you can't expect everybody to build their plugins with the *exact* same compiler and version as your app. Barring that, you can't share C++ objects and APIs across module boundaries. Since you appear to be targetting Windows, use COM which was meant for precisely that, and is reasonably C++ friendly.

Answer (score 1):

In `Fruit* f = (Fruit*)GetProcAddress(concreteLib, "CreateModule");` you are getting the `CreateModule` function address, not calling it.

You have to create a function pointer and call it. (Not compiled example.)

```
typedef Fruit* (*CreateModuleFunc)(void);

CreateModuleFunc CreateModule = GetProcAddress(concreteLib, "CreateModule");

Fruit* f = CreateModule();

f-> // whatever
```